# Symfony get user defined with different classes for roles

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, roles

I have two roles in my application, for example `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_SUPERUSER`. Users are stored in the database using Doctrine.  Users with the `ROLE_USER` role are based on a simple `User` class. (Getters and setters have been removed for readability.)

#### Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User.php

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;
 
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
 
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
* @ORM\Table("users")
* @UniqueEntity(
*       fields={"email"},
*       message="email already used"
* )
*/
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    private $salt;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4096)
     */
    private $password;
 
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;
 
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }
 
    /**
    * @inheritDoc
    */
    public function getRoles()
    {
    return array('ROLE_USER','ROLE_SUPERUSER');
    }
 
}
```

I have a `SuperUser` class that extends `User` to provides more fields that only users with `ROLE_SUPERUSER` would need.

Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SuperUser.php

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;
 
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 
 
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="super_users")
 */
class SuperUser extends User
{
 
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;
 
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;
 
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    proteced $avatar;
 
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, unique=true)
     */
    proteced $username;
 
}
```

In my controllers I'm using `$user = $this -> getUser();` to get the current user, but this returns an instance of the `User` class and I cannot access the `SuperUser` properties or methods, even if the user has the role `ROLE_SUPERUSER`.

For example, I would like to be able to use the following code.

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPERUSER')) {
    $avatar = $this->getUser()-> avatar;
}
```

Is there anyway to be able to do that? I would say there's something to do with Doctrine relationships, but I don't really know what to change.

By the way, as you can see I don't have an `username` field in my standard `User` class, it's only present in `SuperUser`. Does this may cause any problems since the authentication is based on `username`?

---

I think my problem hasn't been clearly exposed, but this might be due to my current code, which is wrong.

I don't have two user tables. I want only one `User` class (with one *users* table). The authentication is operated only on this class with email and password.
I have another class ```` SuperUser```that provides extra fields to users that have the ```` ROLE_SUPERUSER`` role, but the superusers are users and have an entry in the *users* table. I just want to create a left join on the concerned rows, that's why I used inheritance. (Maybe there's a better way to do it.)

If I want to get all the emails, I can query the *users* table. If I want to get all the usernames, since only superusers have one, I can query the *superusers* table.

Comment: i would like to advice you to keep just one user class. Add a extra column with the name isSuperUser to register who is normal user and who is super user. Give as much extra columns for superuser as you need but make sure that the values for this columns may be NULL

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice. It's going against fundamentals of object-oriented programming and creates inconsistent data model.

Comment: No. It is not. What if a user logs in. You want to check two tables if the users exists and entered the right password. What if you want to show a list of users on alphabetical order? Most starters want to extend a class too often. In fact there are only a few circumstances that are good to use the extend keyword.

Comment: Ok. From what you're telling and the following answer I think I misexplained the problem. I"m editing my post.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for two entities with a OneToOne relationship (No extends)

```
/** @Entity **/
class SuperUser
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="superUser")
     **/
    private $user;

    // ...
}

/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SuperUser", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $superUser;

    // ...
}
```

Otherwise take a look at [Inheritance Mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Comment: This works fine, except that I have to do ``$user->getSuperUser->getUsername()`` to get username and I would like to be able to do it only with ``$user->getUsername()``, that's why I tried an extend.

Comment: That is right but doctrine's basic rule is one entity == one table. You could add a method in the User entity getUsername() { if($user) return $user->getUsername(); else return NULL; }

Answer (score 0):

You should have two user providers then, and use one master provider:

```
security:
    providers:
        master_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [user, super_user]

        user:
            entity: { class: Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
        super_user:
            entity: { class: Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SuperUser, property: username }

        firewalls:
            main:
                provider: master_provider
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/multiple_user_providers.html